# React trying to execute methods on undefined variables before they load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you can tell from my title Im not even sure what to call the problem.

I created an example here in code sandbox 
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-poitras-5bcuv?file=/src/Demo.js

If its a wait for the value to be set problem, I've read I need to implement a loading state of some sort? I've attempted that here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-antonelli-tu624?file=/src/Demo.js

but can't seem to get it to work, and I don't know if I am even on the right track.

I've been working with react for a couple of months now, and one of the things I don't completely understand is:

It seems like the code runs multiple times, the first time it will pass the default state of {} as value to my demo component, the state will be set and it will pass the actual value in.

My app is crashing before the actual value gets passed in because of the split.

In the past, I've managed by just throwing a bunch of if and &&  statements at the problem like below, but is this the best way?

```
const split = props.values.home && props.values.home.split("-")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a safe check there. Your problem is a normal js problem, you cannot access a prop of an `undefined` type

just change: `props.values?.home?.split("-") || [];` (as stackblitz supports optional chaining)

and it will work as you expect